# "ImportError: cannot import name..." when trying to run Python script in Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, import, pushover

I have a Python script I would like to run in a Docker container but it stops with error:

```
 File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
   from pushover import init, Client
ImportError: cannot import name 'init' from 'pushover' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pushover/__init__.py)
```

In PyCharm the script runs fine. The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install git python3 python3-pip -y; \ 
   git clone https://(path to my script) ; \
   pip3 install pushover
WORKDIR "/FNotify/"
CMD  python3 main.py;
```

and my imports in the script look like this:

```
from pushover import init, Client
import os
from time import sleep
```

Comment: [That library's source](https://github.com/laprice/pushover/blob/master/pushover/pushover.py) doesn't suggest it has a function named `init`.  Does the same setup work in a non-Docker virtual environment?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, on my Windows environment with pyCharm it works flawless.

Answer (score 0):

You make confuse for [wrong package](https://pypi.org/project/pushover/) & [correct package](https://pypi.org/project/python-pushover/), so what you should install is next:

```
pip3 install python-pushover
```

The result:

```
# python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pushover import init
>>>
```

Also, the `python-pushover` webpage gives the example usage which same as yours:

```
from pushover import init, Client

init("<token>")
Client("<user-key>").send_message("Hello!", title="Hello")
```

Comment: @HardwareFuture You could accept this answer if it resolves your issue.